# Can't connect even though IPtables is stopped

Tags: centos, iptables

I have two network interfaces in my CentOS 5.8 machine, one with a local IP and one with an external, publicly available, IP. I'm running SSH and some other services. I can access these if I connect to the local IP of the machine from some other machine in the same local network. But if I connect from another machine to the external, public IP of the machine, I can't get in.

Even though I disabled the IPtables firewall with `service iptables stop`, it won't work.
Any suggestions? I have tried with SELinux disabled (`setenforce 0`) and also by adding ports to the `setup` firewall configuration. I did check with netstat and both the SSH service and other services are listening to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: What did you get on the client when connecting via public IP? Also post the `/var/log/secure` on the server.

Comment: [root@xxx ~]# ssh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out

Nothing is added to /var/log/secure

Comment: `netstat -nlp | grep :22`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the router is forwarding the inbound traffic.  Additionally, verify that there are no odd rules in `/etc/hosts.deny`.

Comment: Apparently there was some hardware firewall I didn't know of, so the problem wasn't in CentOS nor IPtables. Thanks for helping!